# How to make reduce add all the items into the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I have a data file and I have to turn it into another format using reduce() method, I have written the code but its not adding all the items...

*DATA FILE:*
**data.txt**

```
Joey    Pizza    2
Joey    Sandwich    1
Joey    Burger    2
Chandler    Pizza    1
Chandler    Sandwich    0
Chandler    Burger    1
```

**Expected result**

```
{
  "Joey": [
    {
      "Ordername": "Pizza",
      "Quantity": "2"
    },
    {
      "Ordername": "Sandwich",
      "Quantity": "1"
    },
    {
      "Ordername": "Burger",
      "Quantity": "2"
    }
  ],
  "Chandler": [
    {
      "Ordername": "Pizza",
      "Quantity": "1"
    },
    {
      "Ordername": "Sandwich",
      "Quantity": "0"
    },
    {
      "Ordername": "Burger",
      "Quantity": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I wrote:

**code.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

var output = fs
    .readFileSync('data.txt', 'utf8')
    .trim()
    .split('\n')
    .map((line) => line.split('    '))
    .reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item[0]] = [];
        acc[item[0]].push({ Ordername: item[1], Quantity: item[2] });
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

On running above code its giving **this result**:

```
{
  "Joey": [
    {
      "Ordername": "Burger",
      "Quantity": "2\r"
    }
  ],
  "Chandler": [
    {
      "Ordername": "Burger",
      "Quantity": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why it is only adding third item into the array and not all the three items?

Comment: This `acc[item[0]] = [];` should be `acc[item[0]] = acc[itiem[0]] || [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you always overwrite the key with the name:

`acc[item[0]] = [];`

instead you should do something like

```
if(!acc[item[0]]) {
  acc[item[0]] = []
}

acc[item[0]].push(...)
```

Comment: Though your solution is correct, this can be a shortcut: `acc[item[0]] = acc[itiem[0]] || []`

Comment: if you are looking for a short solution then yes, thats fine too